# I get a blank page on Firefox (only h2 showing)

Tags: javascript, html

This is the page written, and I should be getting "I can print", but I only get the title, and the rest of the page is blank. Where is the mistake?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Object exercise 4</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Object exercise 4</h2>
<script type = "text/javascript">

function PrintStuff(myDocuments)
{
    this.documents = myDocuments;
}

PrintStuff.prototype.print=function()
{
console.log(this.documents);
}

var newObj = new PrintStuff("I can print");
newObj.print();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're printing to the console, not the HTML page.

Comment: The browser does not show content inside the script tag.

Comment: ... So it"s normal you've only got the H2 content printed on screen.

Comment: You probably want to change `console.log(this.documents);` to `document.write(this.documents);` or else create a new HTML element like a `<div>` or `<p>` and put "I can print" there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

console.log() is not what is used to add content to the page. There are several ways of solving your problem - I have added one of those as a code snippet:

```js
function PrintStuff(myDocuments) {
  this.documents = myDocuments;
}

PrintStuff.prototype.print = function() {
  var paragraph = document.createElement("p");
  paragraph.innerText = this.documents;
  document.body.appendChild(paragraph);
  
  console.log(this.documents); // this only prints to the browser console (and throws an exception in IE if the console was not opened before)
}

var newObj = new PrintStuff("I can print");
newObj.print();
```

```html
<h2>Object exercise 4</h2>
```

If you do not know what the browser console is, press [F12] in the browser (it is really helpful) or see [What are browser developer tools?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) (all the stuff at developer.mozilla.org is awesome).

Comment: freginold , I tried it, makes complete sense, but not working

Comment: I basically only added three lines. I removed most of the html for the code snippet as it is not needed to demonstrate what you are looking for. If you only add the three new lines in PrintStuff.prototype.print() to your code, it should work.

Comment: Make sure that the browser is not using a cached copy without your changes. And use the developer tools of the browser ([F12]) to analyse the page or look for exceptions in the console.

Comment: @Yozex which part isn't working?  Gordian's code snippet above works perfectly (I'm using IE 11 right now).  Do you get an error in the console/dev tools?

Comment: like Gordian said make sure you're not loading a cached copy.  (I think) <CTRL> <F5> loads a fresh copy in Firefox.

Comment: @freginold I did the document.write change, and still get the blank page.

Comment: @freginold continuing, tried CTRL F5. I get the desired text in the console (pressing f12), but not on the page.

Comment: Ok, I have completely retyped it into a new file and now it works. In previous version I did some copy paste onto the existing file, and saved it under different name. Probably it did have something to do with the cache.

Comment: Thanks you all for the help!